# What internal functions are undocumented in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, functions, database-internals

I just read about [`fn_dblog`](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/), and `fn_dump_dblog`. I was wondering how do I know what functions like this exist,

I'm not the only one either, the comments are scattered with people wanting to know more,

> Thank you for your post about the fn_dump_dblog it was very interesting. This post makes me want to look through what other cool undocumented functions exist.

Comment: Undocumented functions, are well, undocumented for a reason.  You shouldn't be using them.

Comment: They are undocumented to avoid foot-self-shooting events.

Comment: @MaxVernon I didn't say I was going to use them. What if I want to secure them so others don't use them or audit them for security implications, or use them to learn about the database?

Comment: Whip out your debugger, and go to town.  If you then have an explicit question about a single function that will benefit the community, feel free to ask it.  If it's a good question, it'll likely get a good response.

Comment: The other note to make about undocumented functions is they may change (or go away) from one version to the next, without notice. Another reason they are generally considered as something not to rely on in production code (not that Evan was going to do so, just to note for the sake of (relative) completeness).

Answer (score 1):

> **Note** taken from [sys.sysobjects (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysobjects-transact-sql)
>
> *This SQL Server 2000 system table is included as a view for backward compatibility. We recommend that you use the current SQL Server system views instead. To find the equivalent system view or views, see [Mapping System Tables to System Views (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/mapping-system-tables-to-system-views-transact-sql). This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.*

Everything is documented in the `master` database, unless it is an extended stored procedure, in which case some information is stored in an external `*.DLL` file.

You might want to consider having a look at the `sys.system_objects` table, which contains a wealth of information:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.system_objects WHERE name LIKE '%fn_dblog%'
```

Of course, you could omit the search predicate and enjoy the information overflow of the 2072 objects found in a SQL Server 2014 instance:

```
select left(NAME,60), left(type_desc,35), is_ms_shipped from sys.system_objects
```

Showing the top 100 `system_objects`:

```
name                                                         type_desc                           is_ms_shipped
------------------------------------------------------------ ----------------------------------- -------------
sp_MSalreadyhavegeneration                                   SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSwritemergeperfcounter                                   SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
TABLE_PRIVILEGES                                             VIEW                                1
sp_replsetsyncstatus                                         EXTENDED_STORED_PROCEDURE           1
sp_replshowcmds                                              SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_publishdb                                                 SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_addqueued_artinfo                                         SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_replcounters                                              EXTENDED_STORED_PROCEDURE           1
sp_MSget_subscription_dts_info                               SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_help_spatial_geometry_index_xml                           SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_password                                                  SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
dm_resource_governor_resource_pool_volumes                   VIEW                                1
sp_MSstopdistribution_agent                                  SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_replmonitorrefreshjob                                     SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_redirect_publisher                                        SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSenumpartialchangesdirect                                SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSupdate_subscriber_info                                  SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSdrop_distribution_agent                                 SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_bindsession                                               EXTENDED_STORED_PROCEDURE           1
sp_MSallocate_new_identity_range                             SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSenum_snapshot                                           SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_replsendtoqueue                                           EXTENDED_STORED_PROCEDURE           1
sp_dropmergepullsubscription                                 SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MShelpvalidationdate                                      SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
dm_os_hosts                                                  VIEW                                1
sp_cycle_errorlog                                            SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSgetdynamicsnapshotapplock                               SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_rename                                                    SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_dropremotelogin                                           SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_addpullsubscription                                       SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
xp_instance_regread                                          EXTENDED_STORED_PROCEDURE           1
sp_cdc_disable_table                                         SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_is_makegeneration_needed                                  SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSaddmergedynamicsnapshotjob                              SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSrepl_agentstatussummary                                 SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_changelogreader_agent                                     SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
dm_os_memory_brokers                                         VIEW                                1
sp_MSdynamicsnapshotjobexistsatdistributor                   SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_procedure_params_100_rowset2                              SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
dm_db_stats_properties_internal                              SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION    1
sp_MSenum_merge_subscriptions                                SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_autostats                                                 SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
fn_sqlvarbasetostr                                           SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION                 1
sp_assemblies_rowset_rmt                                     SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_columns_90_rowset_rmt                                     SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MScomputemergearticlescreationorder                       SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
dm_exec_cached_plan_dependent_objects                        SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION    1
sp_addserver                                                 SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSchecksnapshotstatus                                     SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MShelp_distribution_agentid                               SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSaddlightweightmergearticle                              SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
openkeys                                                     VIEW                                1
sp_MSarticlecleanup                                          SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSexecwithlsnoutput                                       SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_new_parallel_nested_tran_id                               EXTENDED_STORED_PROCEDURE           1
dm_os_memory_allocations                                     VIEW                                1
sp_MShelp_identity_property                                  SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_replicationdboption                                       SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MScreate_sub_tables                                       SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_start_user_instance                                       EXTENDED_STORED_PROCEDURE           1
sp_MSresetsnapshotdeliveryprogress                           SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSremove_mergereplcommand                                 SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
dm_db_xtp_nonclustered_index_stats                           VIEW                                1
dm_db_mirroring_past_actions                                 VIEW                                1
dm_xe_session_object_columns                                 VIEW                                1
fn_cdc_get_column_ordinal                                    SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION                 1
sp_MSadd_repl_command                                        SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSgetagentoffloadinfo                                     SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSgetconflicttablename                                    SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_script_reconciliation_sinsproc                            SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSinsertgenerationschemachanges                           SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
dm_os_loaded_modules                                         VIEW                                1
sp_MSgetlightweightmetadatabatch                             SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSNonSQLDDLForSchemaDDL                                   SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
fn_replreplacesinglequoteplusprotectstring                   SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION                 1
sp_dropextendedproc                                          SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSdopartialdatabasesnapshotinitiation                     SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_help_fulltext_catalogs_cursor                             SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
dm_db_task_space_usage                                       VIEW                                1
sp_MSadd_replcmds_mcit                                       SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_changemergesubscription                                   SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSgetonerow                                               SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSquerysubtype                                            SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSevaluate_change_membership_for_pubid                    SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSrepl_dropdatatypemappings                               SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSdetect_nonlogged_shutdown                               SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_change_log_shipping_primary_database                      SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
fn_dump_dblog                                                SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION    1
sp_MSrepl_gettype_mappings                                   SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSenum_distribution                                       SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSrepl_enumpublishertables                                SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSsetupbelongs                                            SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
dm_os_memory_objects                                         VIEW                                1
sp_columns_rowset_rmt                                        SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_grantdbaccess                                             SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_helpsort                                                  SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSscriptviewproc                                          SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_distcounters                                              SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSgettrancftsrcrow                                        SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
sp_MSactivatelogbasedarticleobject                           SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE                1
```

> Note: The listing will contain both documented and undocumented objects.

Comment: Except a lot of these are already documented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-hosts-transact-sql I'm working on mapping in the others now. I think they're also in sys.objects as `P` but I'll check out the system_objects table tomorrow.

Comment: hey @hot2use I think you need to limit your answer to undocumented objects only (undocumented functions) because it doesn't answer the question. Most of the list you posted are stored proc, views.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the only way to find these is to hunt. For starters, both of these functions are typed [`IF` which is *"In-lined table-function"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysobjects-transact-sql) you have

```
SELECT name FROM sys.sysobjects
WHERE type = 'IF' OR xtype = 'IF'
ORDER BY name;
```

However, they're certainly not all "undocumented".  From that list, you'll have to check it against `learn.microsoft.com`. For completion here is the list as of SQL Server 2017 generated with [`find_undocumented.mjs`](https://github.com/EvanCarroll/sql-server-toolz)

```
dm_db_database_page_allocations
dm_db_objects_disabled_on_compatibility_level_change
dm_db_stats_properties_internal
dm_logconsumer_cachebufferrefs
dm_logconsumer_privatecachebuffers
dm_logpool_consumers
dm_logpool_sharedcachebuffers
dm_logpoolmgr_freepools
dm_logpoolmgr_respoolsize
dm_logpoolmgr_stats
dm_os_enumerate_filesystem
dm_os_file_exists
fn_column_store_row_groups
fn_dblog
fn_dblog_xtp
fn_dump_dblog
fn_dump_dblog_xtp
fn_full_dblog
```

Comment: You might want to consider querying against the `sys.system_objects` table instead of the deprecated `sys.sysobjects` table.